# Nokogiri stopped searching for sub tags

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, open-uri

I was writing my ruby (2.0) script which reads a web page & it was working fine. Then I installed ruby 2.2 and suddenly my nokogiri stopped searching sub tags but not all. It still finds some sub tag and some aren't just being found in the same script.
I reverted back to 1.9 but its still doing the same thing. Currently I have installed ruby 2.1.6. I am loading pages with Watir-webdriver and open-uri. The following page is being opened by open-uri.

For an example, here is my code:

```
htmlPage = '<html>
              <head></head>
              <body>
                <table width="100%" border="1">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr valign="top">
                      <td width="38%" bgcolor="#EFEFEF">
                        <b>
                          <font size="4">NPL Listing History</font>
                        </b>
                      </td>
                      <td width="62%" bgcolor="#EFEFEF">
                        <b>
                          <font size="4">Dates</font>
                        </b>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </body>
            <html>'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(htmlPage)

puts page.css("table [border='1']")
```

This should get me the table with border 1 but I get nil/null.

Am I doing something wrong? Or something I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Your selector says "get all of the elements that have a `bgcolor` attribute equal to `#FFFFFF` and are children of `body`." If you just want the whole body, use the selector `body`.

Comment: Okay, bad example! I will change it. What I want is table with border=1, @Jordan

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't point us to a page, instead reduce the HTML to the bare minimum necessary to replicate the problem you're seeing. *When* that URL rots the question won't make sense or be of use to anyone else. With the minimum HTML embedded in the page that won't happen. And, asking us to chase down the URL and look through a full HTML page only slows our ability to help you, so help us help you and put what we need in the question itself. See "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the space. In CSS selectors whitespace is the descendant combinator, so `table [border='1']` means "all descendants of a `table` that have a `border` attribute equal to `1`. What you want is `table[border='1']`, which means "all `table` elements that have a `border` attribute equal to `1`."

Comment: Thank you, Thank you! For whatever reason, it used to work before just fine so I just assumed that it was fine.